# How to delete My Local File

Tags: grails, groovy

This My file Location */opt/dataFileUpload/temp/purchaseOrder/PO-8.pdf*, I want to delete PO-8.pdf file.[Note: Only i want to delete The File Not the Folder Path]

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: How you wanted to delete file manually or grammatically?

Comment: what have you tried so far? searches here for "delete file [groovy]" or "delete file [java]" bring up alot hits

Comment: @Nitin Dhomse I want to delete with my groovy code, and i got that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It should just be:

```
new File('/opt/dataFileUpload/temp/purchaseOrder/PO-8.pdf').delete()
```

(assuming you have the access rights)